# robots.txt - exclude any URL that contains "/node/"

Tags: seo, robots.txt

How do I tell crawlers / bots not to index any URL that has /node/ pattern?
Following is since day one but I noticed that Google has still indexed a lot of URLs that has
/node/ in it, e.g. www.mywebsite.com/node/123/32

Disallow: /node/

Is there anything that states that do not index any URL that has /node/
Should I write something like following:
Disallow: /node/*

Update:
The real problem is despite:
Disallow: /node/
in robots.txt, Google has indexed pages under this URL e.g. www.mywebsite.com/node/123/32

/node/ is not a physical directory, this is how drupal 6 shows it's content, I guess this is my problem that node is not a directory, merely part of URLs being generated by drupal for the content, how do I handle this? will this work?

Disallow: /*node

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`Disallow: /node/` will disallow any url that starts with `/node/` (after the host). The asterisk is not required.

So it will block www.mysite.com/node/bar.html, but will not block www.mysite.com/foo/node/bar.html.

If you want to block anything that contains `/node/`, you have to write `Disallow: */node/`

Note also that Googlebot can cache robots.txt for up to 7 days. So if you make a change to your robots.txt today, it might be a week before Googlebot updates its copy of your robots.txt. During that time, it will be using its cached copy.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, the following tester gave an error for this syntax: http://www.searchenginepromotionhelp.com/m/robots-text-tester/robots-checker.php
It says it must start with a / and not *
I'm not sure how correct this tool is? please guide

Comment: Then you could try two different lines: `Disallow: /node/` for things that start with `/node/`, and `Disallow: /*/node/` for things that have `/node/` embedded somewhere else in the path.

Comment: how about:
Disallow: /node/
and
Disallow: /node/*

Does the later means anything and everything inside /node/ ?

Comment: `/node/` and `/node/*` do the same thing: They disallow anything that starts with `/node/`.

Comment: Should it not be:

    Disallow: /*/node/

You missed a forward slash.

Comment: @moobot: `/*/node/` would block `/foo/node/`, but wouldn't block '/node/foo/`. That pattern would require something between those first two slashes.

Answer (score 1):

`Disallow: /node/*` is exactly what you want to do. Search engines support wildcards in their robots.txt notation and the * characters means "any characters". See [Google's notes on robots.txt](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) for more.

**update**

An alternative way to make sure search engines stay out of a directory, and all directories below it, is to block them with the robots HTTP header. This can be done by placing the following in an htaccess file in your `node` directory:

```
Header set x-robots-tag: noindex
```

Comment: Google's notes on robots.txt says:

To block a directory and everything in it, follow the directory name with a forward slash.

Disallow: /junk-directory/ 
It does not say:
Disallow: /junk-directory/*

so if I've already written correct directive
Disallow: /node/
then why my pages inside it are indexed? e.g. www.mywebsite.com/node/123/32

Comment: Did you add the robots.txt file before or after the pages were indexed? Robots.txt has been known from time to time to not be honored by search engines for unknown reasons. I updated my answer to include an alternative method that works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your original Disallow was fine. Jim Mischel's comment seemed spot on and would cause me to wonder if it was just taking time for Googlebot to fetch the updated robots.txt and then unindex relevant pages.

A couple additional thoughts:

Your page URLs may appear in Google search results even if you've included it in robots.txt. See: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449 ("...While Google won't crawl or index the content of pages blocked by robots.txt, we may still index the URLs if we find them on other pages on the web."). To many people, this is counter-intuitive.

Second, I'd highly recommend verifying ownership of your site in Google Webmaster Tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en), then using tools such as Health->"Fetch as Google" to see real time diagnostics related to retrieving your page. (Does that result indicate that robots.txt is preventing crawling?)

I haven't used it, but Bing has a similar tool: http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/fetch-as-bingbot-fe18fa0d . It seems well worthwhile to use diagnostic tools provided by Google, Bing, etc. to perform *real-time* diagnostics  on the site.

This question is a bit old, so I hope you've solved the original problem.